# How to use ViewModels from another project in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

During trying out Razor I moved my view models and controllers to separate project and switched to nuget library Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core instead Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, so now i have base class for controllers `ControllerBase` and not `Controller` and I don't have method `View(object viewModel)` to return and setup view model for a page.

Now I have methods like `Ok(object data)` which just then returns JSON to my page, and instead of rendering the view, i get raw JSON.

So the question is how to setup View Model for a page properly in this case?

Comment: You've essentially turned your MVC View Controller into an API Controller by inheriting from ControllerBase instead of Controller.  This link provides more background: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clearer view, I switched away from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc as it was not fully compatible with .NET Core and later, so I had to search for equivalent in NET Core world.

After comment to my question I realized I can't use `ControllerBase`, while it was very temtping and easy and *almost* worked.

But then I found (or VS suggested :P ) nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures which had `Controller` abstract class that contains desired method `View(object viewModel)` that works correctly.